# OS X: Set up one folder as "extension" of another, symlink-style?

Tags: macos, finder, symlink

I have two folders on two different Volumes:

- `/Volumes/SSD/my-important-folder`
- `/Volumes/HDD/my-extension-of-important-folder`

In the second folder I put large files and folders so they do not take up all the space on the SSD. In order to have everything in one place I create symlinks from the first to the second folder, like so:

`/Volumes/SSD/my-important-folder/big-file` is a symlink to `/Volumes/HDD/my-extension-of-important-folder/big-file`

This is useful because big files get stored on the HDD yet they are available as if they were stored on the SSD. But this has the disadvantage that I have to create a symlink for every file oder folder that I add to the folder on HDD.

It would be really useful if I could say to the OS: if I call a file that is not in `/Volumes/SSD/my-important-folder`, please look it up in `/Volumes/HDD/my-extension-of-important-folder`.

The folder on the HDD would then be a real extension of the folder on the SSD.

Can this be done? I am running OS X 10.9.1

Comment: Good point, Mark.

Comment: Note this scenario is what a fusion drive works well for, the commonly used files will be on SSD and the others on the HD - you can set up fusion drives yourself - see other questions

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, you can't do that directly but I'm not sure I understand why you'd want to?

Why not just symlink the *entire* folder and never worry about it going forward?

If it's important to you that it's only large files that are moved to the HDD, you could create a **Folder Action** in Automator and run a bash script that checked file size and based on that moved and created the `symlink` automatically (I'm assuming you've got *some* tech skill since you know what `symlink` even is :) With that said, I'd be happy to post more detailed instructions if need be).

Comment: I do not want to Symlink the entire folder because as far as I know I will then not be able to have some files available on the SSD and others on the HDD.
Thank you for the tip on folder Automation.

Answer (score 1):

I would look at this in another way.

I would create several folders in the filesystem:

```
/Volumes/SSD/Data
/Volumes/SSD/ActualDataOnSSD
/Volumes/HDD/ActualDataOnHDD
```

Then folder actions.

If any data get stored in `/Volumes/SSD/Data` based on its size and **move** it to one of the two folders.

If any data get stored in `/Volumes/SSD/ActualDataOnSSD` or `/Volumes/HDD/ActualDataOnHDD`, create a symlink for them in `/Volumes/SSD/Data`.

This seems to satisfy you need, **however** I do have **big** concerns when it comes to saving a file that's being moved.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a command like this:

```
ln -s /dir2/* /dir1
```

`ln` skips files that exist on the target, and it doesn't recreate existing symlinks.

To run the command when `/dir2/` is modified, save for example this plist as `~/Library/LaunchAgents/some.label.plist`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>some.label</string>
  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
    <string>bash</string>
    <string>-c</string>
    <string>ln -s /dir2/* /dir1</string>
  </array>
  <key>WatchPaths</key>
  <array>
    <string>/dir2/</string>
  </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Then run `launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/some.label.plist`.

Comment: Thanks, Lauri. As far as I can see this would create a Symlink for every file on the SSD, right? I want to be able to choose which files and folders are symlinked.